# How to return something in a table form if it does not exist in the database table. Is it possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server

First I thank you for looking at my question. The context is that let's say I have a table `customer_table`. There is customer ID , customer name, customer address as fields.

In the table there are 3 customers. Customer 1, 2 and 3 each with their respective names and addresses. Say I use this query,

```
select * from customer_table where customer_ID = 1
```

I get the data of the first customer.

Now I want use this query

`select * from   customer_table where customer_ID = 5`

I only get the field names and nothing in return.

Is there a way to get a table for the second result where the id does not exist. For example,

```
5 - null - null
```

Thanks again!

Comment: No, You cannot. `null` is a value, it is called `known value` but still a value, but in your table there is no id equals 5, so the result set MUST be empty NOT Null

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert NULL if query returns nothing in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65829366/insert-null-if-query-returns-nothing-in-sql-server)

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader Of course you can, just start with a `VALUES` constructor and left join everything else

Comment: @Charlieface, Thank you for giving me this information.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @customer_ID int

set @customer_ID  = 3

;WITH cteid AS
      (
      SELECT @customer_ID AS customer_ID
      )

select @customer_ID as p_customer_ID,main.* from 
cteid cte
LEFT JOIN customer_table main ON cte.customer_ID = main.customer_ID
```

Comment: you can use main.parameter name instead of * in case you don't want to select entire table

Answer (score 1):

One method uses a `left join`:

```
select v.customer_id, ct.col1, ct.col2
from (values (1)
     ) v(customer_id) left join
     customer_table ct
     on ct.customer_id = v.customer_id;
```

Another method uses aggregation, which works if you are only looking for one row:

```
select 1 as customer_id, max(col1) as col1, max(col2) as col2
from customer_table 
where customer_id = 1;
```